# Merging *.Designer.cs files

Tags: winforms, tfs, merge, version-control, windows-forms-designer

I am facing difficulty in merging Windows Forms designer files. Because whenever we work on the same windows form and modify the design visual studio will re-order the designer code at that time we spent many hours to merge that 100 lines of code.it's very painful.

So can you provide any guidance on merging these files? I'm looking for anyone with experience with this issue who may have found some tips or workarounds.

thanks,

Comment: Don't merge them. As part of the conflict resolution process, let them be re-generated.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielMann, But what I have to do when multiple people working on the same designer. we need to merge them.

Comment: Designer files aren't intended to be manually edited.

Comment: @DanielMann, I don't see any "source" files for the .Designer.cs files representing Windows Forms GUI. Where are they?